# How to turn off calculating pyramids during image processing?

Tags: image-processing

I am using Erdas 2014 to run a 5x5 focal median filter on a batch of images (Raster Tab > Spatial > Focal Analysis (batch)). These images will eventually be resampled to a different pixel size, and therefore I do not want to spend the processing time calculating pyramids. How can I turn off pyramids while performing batch image processing in Erdas 2014?

Answer (score 1):

Pyramids can be toggled on and off using the Erdas preferences: File > Preferences > File Formats > Image Files (General).

[image]